# stubbing method with async callback in sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, sinon

I have a `parsePDF()` method that calls `extractText()`, which returns its results in an async callback.

### the question

How do I write a test that tests *only* that `parsePDF` calls `extractText` once, and with whatever `path` argument was passed to `parsePDF`?  (I have separate unit tests for `extractText` and `cleanUp`.)

Here's the basic structure of the `parsePDF` method:

```
Parser.parsePDF(path, callback) {
  Parser.extractText(path, function gotResult(err, raw_text) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err)
      return;
    }
    var clean_text = Parser.cleanUp(raw_text)
    callback(null, clean_text);
  });
};
```

### what I've tried

Despite reading the [Sinon documentation on callsArg](http://sinonjs.org/docs/), [Mocha/Chai/Sinon tutorials](https://blog.codeship.com/mocha-js-chai-sinon-frontend-javascript-code-testing-tutorial/), various SO posts such as [this one about stubbing function with callback - causing test method to timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307058/sinon-stubbing-function-with-callback-causing-test-method-to-timeout), I still haven't grokked what's needed to write a proper test.

This attempt fails with the message

> Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

It makes sense, the callback isn't being fired

```
    it('should call extractText() with path argument', function(done) {
        sandbox.stub(Parser, 'extractText')
        Parser.parsePDF('a known path', function(err, bill) {
            expect(sinon).calledOnce(Parser.extractText).calledWith('a known path')
            done()
        });
    });
```

But the following with `yeilds()` also fails with the message `undefined is not a function` pointing at the `expect...` line:

```
    it('should call extractText() with path argument', function(done) {
        sandbox.stub(UtilityBillParser, 'extractText').yields(null, 'some text')
        Parser.parsePDF('a known path', function(err, bill) {
            expect(sinon).calledOnce(Parser.extractText).calledWith('a known path')
            done()
        });
    });
```

As does the following with `.callsArg(1)`:

```
    it('should call extractText() with path argument', function(done) {
        sandbox.stub(UtilityBillParser, 'extractText').callsArg(1)
        UtilityBillParser.parsePDF('a known path', function(err, bill) {
            expect(sinon).calledOnce(UtilityBillParser.extractText).calledWith('a known path')
            done()
        });
    });
```

Comment: I'm tempted to delete this question: after a few hours of sleep the answer seemed (mostly) obvious: since I'm stubbing out the `extractText()` method, its callback method doesn't get called (which is what I want).  I can pass an empty callback method, and there's no need for the `done()` method.  But I haven't figured out how to validate the argument passed to the stubbed `extractText()` method, so I'll leave the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`parser.js`:

```js
const Parser = {
  parsePDF(path, callback) {
    Parser.extractText(path, function gotResult(err, raw_text) {
      if (err) {
        callback(err);
        return;
      }
      var clean_text = Parser.cleanUp(raw_text);
      callback(null, clean_text);
    });
  },
  extractText(path, callback) {
    callback();
  },
  cleanUp(rawText) {
    return "real clean text";
  },
};

module.exports = Parser;
```

`parser.test.js`:

```js
const Parser = require("./parser");
const sinon = require("sinon");

describe("Parser", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  describe("#parsePDF", () => {
    it("should clean up raw test", () => {
      const callback = sinon.stub();
      sinon.stub(Parser, "extractText").yields(null, "fake raw text");
      sinon.stub(Parser, "cleanUp").returns("fake clean text");
      Parser.parsePDF("./somepath", callback);
      sinon.assert.calledWith(Parser.extractText, "./somepath", sinon.match.func);
      sinon.assert.calledWith(Parser.cleanUp, "fake raw text");
      sinon.assert.calledWith(callback, null, "fake clean text");
    });

    it("should handle err", () => {
      const callback = sinon.stub();
      const mError = new Error("some error");
      sinon.stub(Parser, "extractText").yields(mError, null);
      sinon.stub(Parser, "cleanUp").returns("fake clean text");
      Parser.parsePDF("./somepath", callback);
      sinon.assert.calledWith(Parser.extractText, "./somepath", sinon.match.func);
      sinon.assert.calledWith(callback, mError);
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  Parser
    #parsePDF
      ✓ should clean up raw test
      ✓ should handle err


  2 passing (9ms)

----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File            |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files       |    93.75 |      100 |    77.78 |    93.75 |                   |
 parser.js      |       80 |      100 |       50 |       80 |             13,16 |
 parser.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/30163720

Answer (score 1):

Since you are stubbing out the extractText() method altogether, its callback never gets invoked, so none of the special processing associated with callbacks is required.  The following works:

```
    it('should call extractText() with path argument', function() {
        sandbox.stub(Parser, 'extractText')
        Parser.parsePDF('a known path', 'ignored');
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(Parser.extractText)
        sinon.assert.calledWith(Parser.extractText, 'a known path', sinon.match.func)
    });
```

Using `sinon.match.func` in the second assertion reflects the fact that `parsePDF` creates its own anonymous function to pass to `extractText`; the best you can do is assert that *some* function was passed to `extractText`.

Comment: What if I wanted to test the functionality in the callback as part of my test. This means I can't do that ever right?

Comment: @Prachi: In practice, you'd put the call to stub in a beforeEach(), and then call .restore() in afterEach().  That would put everything back to where it was, so then you could test the callback functionality.  See sinon docs for details.  (Also check out the sandbox feature...)